# Updating child template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, jquery-templates

I have a master template like:

```
<script type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl" id="baseTmpl">
<tr>
    <td>${Name}</td>
    <td>
        <div id="${ID}">
            {{tmpl "#displayTmpl"}}
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</script>  

<script type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl" id="displayTmpl">
    <a id="myLink" href="javascript:changeTmpl(${ID})">${Department}</a>
</script>

<script type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl" id="editTmpl">
    <input type="text" id="text" value="${Department}" />
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeTmpl(id) {
        var templateItem = $('#'+id).tmplItem();    
        templateItem.tmpl = editTemplate;
        templateItem.update();
    };
</script>
```

The above code remove all tr data as well and when I update the template. I want to update the content of just the div rather than full tr

Answer (score 0):

In the base template, the ID should refer to the tr, not the div

```
<tr div id="${ID}">
....
</tr>
```

At the moment, when you select var templateItem = $('#'+id).tmplItem();, it only pulls out the div because that is what the id refers to.

Comment: I anyways have to render the contents of the div only and not the whole tr.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
var templateItem = $('#'+id).tmplItem();
```

You are getting the tmplItem of the div, which is actually the same tmplItem for everything rendered by that template (the whole `<tr>`).

You want to access the tmplItem of the elements inside the div.  This would work:

```
var templateItem = $('#'+id).children(":first").tmplItem();
```